# Problema al crear proyecto en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

He visto en varios tutoriales y en paginas web el modo de crear un proyecto de ruby on rails en los vídeos normalmente se este comando:

```
> rails new Proyecto -d mysql
```

esto quiere decir que esta creando un proyecto en los vídeos muestra que el proyecto se crea con carpetas y todo.

A continuación mostrare imágenes de como creo mi proyecto

> Primero mostrare las versiones que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Al momento de crear el proyecto solo me genera esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun algunos videos tendria que generarme carpetas, pero no se si me falta algo o es que lo tengo mal configurado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no encuentra el comando git para inicializar el repositorio del proyecto.
Tendrias que asegurarte que tienes git instalado y en el PATH o indicarle a rails que no lo intente inicializar de la siguiente manera

```
rails new Proyecto -d mysql --skip-git
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias ya instale git y se crearon las capetas

Comment: Muchas gracias Jeroni Chamorro la verdad tenia el mismo problema pero no encontraba solucion y ya me estaba volviendo loco.
De verdad muchas gracias...